# Trying to access a list I've filled up in form 1 on form 2 but the list is empty?

Tags: c#, winforms

So let me start of by saying I'm extremely new to coding ( followed a course about general programming logic ) and am now messing around with c# winforms. I'm trying to create the game charades in c# winforms and have gotten pretty far already. My form 1 handles all the game setup ( number of players, naming the players, etc ... ), I have a "player" class to create objects and learn myself OOP which seems to be the general way to go with C# from what I've read. However now that I'm trying to work on form 2 it seems the list from the "player" class I've filled up in form 1 is empty when I try to access it on form 2.

Quick rundown on what I'm doing;

-Form 1 loads by default and I put in the number of players and name each player which I then add to a list through a method created in the "player" class.

-Once all players have been named form 1 closes and form 2 opens ( found a bit of code online to get this to work by making a bool switch, when it's set to true it'll execute some code in program.cs to do "Application.run(form2)" so the program can stay active when closing form 1 and showing form 2.

-On form 2 I'm trying to access the list from the "player" class which I can do without a problem by creating a new object of the "player" class in form 2 and creating a method that gets the list from that class, but when I do it's completely empty.

here's the code from form 1, form 2 and player class.

form1 :

```
    using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Pictionary
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public bool Form2Loaded { get; set; }
        private int aantalKliks = 0;
        private int aantalSpelers = 0;

    public Spelers speler1 = new Spelers();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pictionaryTitle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    private void buttonSpelregels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            $"1 - Kies of iedereen voor zichzelf speelt of in teams.{Environment.NewLine}2 - Geef de namen van de spelers in of een team naam per team.{Environment.NewLine}3 - Er word een speler of team gekozen om het woord uit te beelden. Druk op de knop om het woord zichtbaar/onzichtbaar te maken. Druk op de start knop om de ronde te beginnen.{Environment.NewLine}4 - De andere spelers/team hebben 60 seconden de tijd om het woord te raden. Kies de juist optie om de punten toe te voegen.{Environment.NewLine}5 - Druk op de knop stop spel om het spel te stoppen en de punten te laten zien.",
            "Spelregels");
    }

    private void buttonFreeforall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Show();
        buttonBack.Show();
        buttonTeams.Hide();
        buttonFreeforall.Hide();
        buttonSpelregels.Hide();
    }

    private void buttonBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Hide();
        buttonBack.Hide();
        buttonTeams.Show();
        buttonFreeforall.Show();
        buttonSpelregels.Show();
        radioButton2.Checked = false;
        radioButton3.Checked = false;
        radioButton4.Checked = false;
        radioButton5.Checked = false;

    }

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Hide();
        buttonBack.Hide();
        textBox1.Show();
        buttonAddName.Show();
        aantalSpelers = 2;
    }


    private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Hide();
        buttonBack.Hide();
        textBox1.Show();
        buttonAddName.Show();
        aantalSpelers = 3;
    }

    private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Hide();
        buttonBack.Hide();
        textBox1.Show();
        buttonAddName.Show();
        aantalSpelers = 4;
    }

    private void radioButton5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Hide();
        buttonBack.Hide();
        textBox1.Show();
        buttonAddName.Show();
        aantalSpelers = 5;
    }

    private void buttonAddName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox1.Text == "Speler Toegevoegd!")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Naam mag niet blanco zijn!");
        }

        else
        {
            switch (aantalKliks)
            {
                case 0:
                    speler1.naamSpeler = textBox1.Text;
                    speler1.SpelerNaarLijst();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    speler1.naamSpeler = textBox1.Text;
                    speler1.SpelerNaarLijst();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    speler1.naamSpeler = textBox1.Text;
                    speler1.SpelerNaarLijst();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    speler1.naamSpeler = textBox1.Text;
                    speler1.SpelerNaarLijst();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    speler1.naamSpeler = textBox1.Text;
                    speler1.SpelerNaarLijst();
                    break;

            }

            textBox1.Text = "Speler Toegevoegd!";

            aantalKliks = aantalKliks + 1;
        }
        if (aantalKliks == aantalSpelers)
        {
            this.Close();
            Form2Loaded = true;

        }
    }
}
```

}

form 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Pictionary
{
public partial class Form2 : Form

#region generatedCode

{
    public Spelers speler1 = new Spelers();

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     
    }


    private bool buttonSwitch = false;

    private void buttonToggleWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonSwitch = !buttonSwitch;

        if (buttonSwitch == true)
        {
            labelWoord.Text = "Woord: test";

        }

        else
        {
            labelWoord.Text = "Woord: ";
        }
    }

}
#endregion
```

}

player class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pictionary
{
public class Spelers
{
    //Attributes
    public string naamSpeler;
    public List<string> spelerLijst = new List<string>();


    //constructors

    //methods
    public void SpelerNaarLijst()
    {
        spelerLijst.Add(naamSpeler);
    }``

}
```

}

Any help and even some explanation as to why it's not working is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Well, in **both** forms you do `public Spelers speler1 = new Spelers();`. In other words, for each form you create their own **new** Spelers instance. Both forms do **not** access the same spelerLijst list. Each form operates on separate spelerLijst lists, because each form has and works with their own individual Spelers instance.

Comment: FYI: If you want to add a player name by calling SpelerNaarLijst, pass the player name as argument to the method. The method declaration should be something like public `public void SpelerNaarLijst(string playerName)`. Your approach of using an instance field as some sort of quasi method parameter is... unusual.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Like I said I'm new to coding in general so I'm still learning how to do things the proper way, I'll try the way you've given to pass the names to the list. How would I go about getting access to the list then on form 2 if I created the list in form 1 ?

Comment: Depends. Do you have a "main form" that contains form1 and form2?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace No I do not, form 1 is my "main" form, which is the one that gets created by default when using the winform template...

Comment: Okay. I assume form2 is then instantiated by form1. Do you have a field/variable in form1 which refers to form2 (in a similar fashion as the field "flowLayoutPanel1" in your form1 is a reference to some panel in your form1)? You could then keep your `public Spelers speler1` declaration in Form2, but **without** assigning a new Spelers instance. And in form1 constructor, right after the call to InitializeComponent(), you would then assign form1's Spelers instance to the "speler1" field of form2. Doing so would then mean that both form1 and form2 hold a reference to the _same_ Spelers instance.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I have a bool in form 1 that I set to true which then prompts some code in program.cs to load form 2 ;

    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
            Application.Run(frm1);

            if (frm1.Form2Loaded)
            {
                Application.Run(new Form2());
            }

Not sure if that's exactly what you were after but no variables or such in form 1 that refer to form 2 as far as I recall D:

Comment: Oh, alright. Then forget about what i said in my last comment ;-) In both form1 and form2, declare the field `public Spelers speler1` but without assigning a new Spelers instance to it. Rather, create the Spelers instance (once only!) in program.cs (i suppose the Main method), and assign this instance to the speler1 fields of _both_ form1 and form2. (I am off now, bed is calling...)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I finally got it to work properly the way I want it to ! Thanks so much :). Had some trouble getting it to work at first but that was mainly because I'm still extremely new to coding and assigned the form 1 and form 2 fields too late in the code ( after loading the forms instead of right before ). 

Everything works perfectly now, and to top it all of because of your explanation I've actually understood as to why it's working now and why it didn't work before ! I've got a long way to go but thanks to people like you I can learn bit by bit <3.